# Создание таблицы MySQL: CREATE command denied to user

Tags: mysql

Люди, я уже сдаюсь.

Покажите пример создания таблицы в mysql(); Перерыл форумы  и создал

```
$Link = @mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password);
mysqli_select_db($Link, $db_databases) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("CREATE TABLE  `testdb`.`tests` (`id` INT NOT NULL ,`test` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ));
        ") Or die(mysql_error());
```

Получил ошибку

> `CREATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'tests'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А у пользователя, под которым вы коннектитесь к базе, есть привелегии создавать на создание баз?

Comment: $db_host='test1.ru';$db_username='root';$db_password='';скачан с сайта denwer.ru

Comment: скачана строка с сайта или установлен денвер?, сама база testdb существует ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно пользователь, под которым Вы пытаетесь создать базу, не имеет привилегий для подобных действий.

Comment: видимо да!А сам запрос сделан правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь ошибка заключалась в использовании разного обращения mysqli_ и mysql_.
Видимо нужно использовать было везде 1 синтаксис.

```
$connection=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_login,$db_password);

    if(!$connection){
        echo 'connection is wrong';

        }

    //mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE `wwot`") or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('wwot') or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE  `tests` (`id` INT NOT NULL ,`test` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ));
            ") Or die(mysql_error());
```

Тут народился вопрос --а что лучше mysqli_ или mysql?
всем спасибо

Comment: лучше PDO)